# Summation involving combinations

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to find an answer to the following summation:
$$
\frac{1}{2^{2q}(2q+1)}\sum_{m=0}^q \binom{2q+1}{q+m+1}(2m+1)
$$

It was a little uglier than this, but I managed to tidy it up to this point. I also verified my tidying is correct with python.

Edit: Wolfram alpha gives
$$
\frac{q+1}{(2q+1)2^{2q}}\binom{2q+1}{q+1}
$$

This should be enough for me but I still would like to understand how to reach here.

Comment: Note that the answer as given by WA simplifies to $\frac{1}{2^{2q}}\binom{2q}{q}$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein This was actually very helpful. Makes my job so much easier with the stirling approximation for large $q$s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write $2m+1 = 2(q+m+1) - (2q+1)$ and use the identity $\displaystyle(q+m+1)\binom{2q+1}{q+m+1} = (2q+1) \binom{2q}{q+m}$.

Comment: I couldn't make it work yesterday night but today with a clear had, I was able to use your hint! Thank you.